# How to fix index out of range error?

Tags: java, runtime-error

I'm a beginner java programmer and I am trying to make a program which sorts a string into alphabetical order, this code is messy but I am receiving a range out of index error when it eliminates half the string. I am sure this is due to the i being incremented and the l being reduced but I am not sure of a fix, help would be appreciated, and I am not allowed to use the sort function.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Question6{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a string");
        String user = in.nextLine();
    int l = user.length();
    //System.out.println(l);
    int i = 0;
    System.out.println("Length is " + user.length());
    ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
    //System.out.println(first);
    while (l > 0){
        char first = user.charAt(0);
        ArrayList<Character> earliest = new ArrayList<Character>();
        earliest.add(first);
        char char1 = user.charAt(i);
        if (char1 <= earliest.get(0)){
            earliest.remove(0);
            earliest.add(char1);
            user = user.substring(0, i) + user.substring(i+1);
            chars.add(char1);
            System.out.println("earliest in loop " + earliest.toString());
            System.out.println("chars in loop " + chars.toString());
            System.out.println("string is now " + user);
            System.out.println(" ");
            i = i+1;
            }
        else{
            chars.add(first);
            System.out.println("chars in else " + chars.toString());
            i = 0;
        }
        l = user.length();
    }

    System.out.println("done ");        
}
}
```

Error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at Question6.main.(Question6.java:19)
```

This is with the String "Stack" as input

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: Would you prefer your code fixed, or a cleaner solution to sort a string in a similar manner?

Answer (score 1):

[java.lang.String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) implements [java.lang.Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), so you could just do:

```
if (s1.compareTo(s2) < 0) {
    //...
} else if (s1.compareTo(s2) == 0) {
    //...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Also, avoid using `remove(int)` while looping through a `Collection`, prefer using an `Iterator` like this:

```
Iterator<String> ite = myListString.iterator();
String str;
while(ite.hasNext()) {
     str = ite.next();
     if (/* this entry has to be removed from the list */) {
          ite.remove();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you substring your user String at

```
    user = user.substring(0, i) + user.substring(i + 1);
```

and when in while loop your **i (incrementing variable)** in

```
 char char1 = user.charAt(i);
```

is **greater than length of string user** and it tries to access the variable at position which does not exist in your String user then it will throw ArrayIndexOutOfBondException.

for example Your String is "one" and after 2 iterations string will be e and your i will be 2 
so this `char char1 = user.charAt(i)`; will try to access it like
**char char1 = "e".charAt(2);** (which does not exist)

i would suggest to change your logic

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over `l` which is the length of the input string supplied by the user. In each iteration you increase `i` by one. Within the iteration you are accessing the index `i` of the input string. The length of the string stays the same unless you fall into the else case. So sooner or later `i` will be greater than `l - 1` and at position `l` there is no index in the Array.

Besides, as others have already pointed out, there are some other issues.

Try taking a look at various sorting algorithms e.g. http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/